# How to Stop VS 2013 from Generating TypeScript Map Files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript

Does anyone know how to stop VS 2013 from generating *.map files for TypeScript?

We're not such a big fan of them since they:

- Tend to fall out of sync with actual javascript source
- Stop the ability for you to do edit/continue debugging in tools like Chrome Developer Tools

I can delete them with a post build step, but the javascript that gets generated still has a:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=someFile.js.map
```

Which makes the browser look for the map files (generating a 404). Even if we try to build a project that has TypeScript in Release mode it still generates JS with references to map files.

Anyway to stop the pain?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the TypeScript project properties, go to "TypeScript Build" (available starting with TS 0.9.5) and deselect "Generate source maps".

Comment: Note that if you want to perform publish - probably will have to do Rebuild project (right mode) before you make Publish. Not enough to define the current mode in the publish settings - .